# How do I replace column of numbers in excel with their "th" and "nd" ending?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a column of numbers in excel that I would like to replace with their two letter ending "th" "nd" as  in 13th, or 62nd. How do I do this in excel? I do have a big key that has the number and its ending on a separate sheet.

Comment: What you're looking for is the "ordinal number" for those values. Searching for something with that term (maybe "convert number to ordinal excel") should help you find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) are normal numeric numbers and look like: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

[Ordinal numbers](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/cardinal-ordinal-chart.html) have a suffix and look like: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc.

Please note that in ordinal form, numbers are actually text and should only be used for display; Excel will no longer consider them numbers.

If a cardinal number is in `A1` this formula will result in its ordinal representation...

```
=IF(OR(--RIGHT(A1,2)={11,12,13}),"th",IFERROR(CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1),"st","nd","rd"),"th"))
```

The above formula does NOT need to be array entered. Just a normal confirmation will suffice.

For completeness here is a way to use the above surprisingly concise formula as a UDF. Place the following function in a VBA standard code module...

```
Function Ordinal(n)
  Ordinal = n & Evaluate("IF(OR(--RIGHT(" & n & ",2)={11,12,13}),""th"",IFERROR(CHOOSE(RIGHT(" & n & "),""st"",""nd"",""rd""),""th""))")
End Function
```

Now you can call it from a formula on a worksheet. For example, in cell `A1` you could have the following formula:

```
=Ordinal(123)
```

Or from a VBA routine...

```
Msgbox Ordinal(21)
```

And to get and hold an array of the first 255 ordinal numbers in VBA you can use the following variation as a function...

```
Function Ordinals()
  Ordinals = [ROW(1:255)&IF((--RIGHT(ROW(1:255),2)>10)*(--RIGHT(ROW(1:255),2)<14),"th",IFERROR(CHOOSE(RIGHT(ROW(1:255)),"st","nd","rd"),"th"))]
End Function
```

Now get the array like so...

```
Sub Test()
  Dim v  
  v = Ordinals  '<-- v is now a 2d array and holds the first 255 ordinals
  MsgBox v(211, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, comprehensive answer!